# vertex paint final rendering

Tags: rendering, color

I painted my object in vertex paint (cycles) and it looks great in rendered view, but on final picture render it has white spots on it. Did anyone had the same problem? Thank you

nodes: attribute - diffuse BSDF - material output

[image]

Comment: Try to press Alt+H while in viewport and see if there's an object in the same spot as the one you created material for

Comment: Mr Zak thank you so much! Yes there is. I'm so stupid that I didn't know that final render renders  hidden objects... It was my sculpt under retopology object.

Answer (score 1):

There are two independent switches to make an object visible:

The **Eye** icon toggles visibility in the viewport

The **Camera** icon toggles visibility at render time

[image]

Pressing <kbd>H</kbd> to hide an object will only make the object invisible in the viewport, but not for render. The object will be visible when you render unless you switch off the camera.